# Inverse functions of certain conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Suppose I have a family of conformal maps given by $\omega=z+az^n$ where $|a|\leq1/n$ which maps the unit disk onto the so called epitrochoid. I am wondering about the inverse conformal map which takes the resultant domain back to the unit disk. For n=2 it's easy to find the inverse simply by treating the entire thing as a quadratic in z and solving, but I was wondering if there was a known inverse for the higher degrees. Obviously there is no general formula for polynomials of degree 5 or higher, but since these are relatively simple maps, I hold out hope that a general formula can be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to expect $az^n+z-w=0$ to be solvable in radicals for $n\ge 5$. Having only three monomials does not make an equation simple.  For example, I took $a=1/10$. With $n=4$, Maple provides a neat solution in radicals:

[image]

With $n=5$ it does not:

[image]